# Show row numbers in GridControl PrintPreview

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have problem with DevExpress GridControl PrintPreview. How can I create column with row numbers in PrintPreview? I need to show ordinal number for each row PrintPreview.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this from a direct export is to add an unbound data column:

1. Go into the grid designer and add a column; name it (`colRowNumber` or whatever)
2. Move the column to be the first column in the layout
3. In the column's properties:

   a. set `UnboundType` to `Integer`

   b. set `OptionsColumn.AllowEdit` set it to `False`
4. Within the grid, create an event for `CustomUnboundColumnData`

Your code for the `CustomUnboundColumnData` event should look something like this:

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender,
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == colRowNumber)
        e.Value = e.ListSourceRowIndex + 1;
}
```

From here, now matter how your grid is ordered or filtered, the "Row Number" column will always contain the 1-based row number of the displayed data.